# 504 Timeout Errors in Vercel Logs for sending message with Whats App API

Tags: next.js, whatsapp

I have a next JS endpoint hosted on vercel that is basically boilerplate code from the whats app API for sending a message. When I send a message I receive a 200 res and get my message back within a couple seconds. I see a 200 res on the vercel server logs but then I see an influx of 504 timeouts following. How can I resolve this? Is this a server config issue or some error in my code?

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import axios from 'axios'

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const mode = req.query['hub.mode']
    const challenge = req.query['hub.challenge']
    const token = req.query['hub.verify_token']

    if (mode && token) {
      if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === myToken) {
        res.status(200).send(challenge)
      } else {
        res.status(403)
      }
    }
  }
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const body = req.body
    if (!secretKey)
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No Secret Key Provided' })

    if (body.object) {
      if (
        body.entry &&
        body.entry[0].changes &&
        body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages &&
        body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0]
      ) {
        let phoneId = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id
        let from = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from
        let msg_body = body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].text.body

        try {
          const response = await generateResponse(msg_body)

          await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/${phoneId}/messages`,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
            data: {
              messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
              to: from,
              text: {
                body: response,
              },
            },
          })

          return res.status(200).end()
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
          return res.status(500).end()
        }
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(404).end()
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(404).end()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Vercel, the server configurations are managed for you, but it's good to keep an eye on logs to see if there are any unusual activities. Add more logging to your functions, so you can capture the flow and find out where it might be failing.